# angular ag-grid setting row color with getRowStyle disables rowSelection color

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid where I want to customize the background color of the rows.

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    this.initialize();
    this.gridOptions.getRowStyle = this.changeRowColor;

}
```

Here is changeRowColor:

```
changeRowColor(params) {
    return {
        'background-color': params.data.backgroundColor
    };
}
```

The problem is that when I enable [rowSelection]="'multiple'" the selected rows are not highlighted. I have determined that these two functionalities are incompatible by commenting out the getRowStyle. When I do that the rows are highlighted on selection.

Does anyone have an idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Your row level styles are overriding default [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid)'s styles.

One way to make the selected row highlighted in this case is to override cell level styles for the selected row.

```
.ag-fresh .ag-row-selected {
    background-color: #66bfff !important;
    .ag-cell {
        background-color: #66bfff !important;
    }
}
```

The above CSS shows the workaraound for `ag-fresh` theme. To make it work for the other themes, add classes accordingly.